# Web-to-Case Attachments

Tags: visualforce, web2case

Is there way to add an attachment field to a Web-to-Case form? I understand this is not out of the box functionality, but would like to know if there is a workaround. If there is a way to do this with Apex and Visualforce, please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using force.com sites for Web-to-case functionality?

Comment: Yes it's hosted on a sites.

Comment: did you try <apex:inputFile> in visualforce?

Comment: Will that allow the attachment to be added to the case when it's created?

Comment: Refer this link: http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com/2011/06/save-attachment-in-apex.html

Comment: Thanks..I'm not sure this would work with OOB Web-to-Case. Is this assuming that a Case record has been created? I'm guessing cases created via Web-to-Case get put into a queue which is different from creating them directly through Apex.